# Simple 2D chart/graph control for winforms .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, charts

I am looking for a .NET 2.0 compatible simple Chart/Graph control to embed in my Winform application. So far I could only found [Zed Graph](http://sourceforge.net/projects/zedgraph/). While it has all the functionality I need and then some, my problem is that its looks too professional for its own good. I tried customizing it and playing with its styling properties but the graph still looked dull.

I need a snazzy looking control which can give a chart that looks similar to this one

[image]

I don't really need all the details Zed Graph gives.

Can someone suggest a free control that can do this. Please bare in mind that the control should work with .NET 2.0

Regards

Comment: _Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NPlot](http://netcontrols.org/nplot/wiki/)

> NPlot (formerly known as scpl) is a free charting library for .NET. It boasts an elegant and flexible API. NPlot includes controls for Windows.Forms, ASP.NET and a class for creating Bitmaps.